# Grapher for Windows?

Tags: windows, graphs, macos, calculator

On a Mac, there is a Grapher.app which has many functions like: ordinary graphing, polar graphing, lin-log and log-log graphing, 3d graphing, derivatives, integrals, implicitly defined functions, equation solvers and much much more.

Is there anything similar for Windows, other than GeoGebra? Or a software able to plot 3D graphs (and possibly implicitly defined functions)? I already heard about Matplotlib, but I don't know any Python...

Otherwise, is there a way to emulate a MacOS on Windows and reproduce the Grapher app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to learn R and start using ggplot2 or python and start using any/all of MatPlatLib, Bokeh, plot.ly or dozens of others then:

Try [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) which is:

- Free, gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform **including Windows**
- Conpact *Current Windows Download is <34 MB*
- Can produce output in multiple formats *including HTML Canvas, gif, pdf, jpeg, png, svg & postscript.*
- Lots of [contributed scripts](http://www.gnuplot.info/scripts/index.html)
- Includes just about every graph type you can think of! From the [Demos for gnuplot version 5.2](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/) page:

### Basic 2D plot styles

```
simple functions
filled curves
fill between curves
candlesticks
error bars
histograms (more)
bar graphs
step functions
multiple axis scales
mixing styles
variable size points
parallel axis plots
parametric functions
piecewise functions
vector fields
circles
boxplots
rug plot
jitter (bee swarm)
text
```

[image]

### Math functions

```
approximation
complex trig functions
complex error function
probability
probability (more)
random numbers
recursion, etc...
data statistics
```

[image]

### Curve fitting

```
cubic and Bezier splines
monotonic csplines
explicit B-splines
explicit Bezier splines
Levenberg-Marquardt DLS
```

[image]

### Animation

```
animated gif
```

[image]

### 3D plots and surfaces

```
surfaces 1
surfaces 2
contours
singularities
hidden surfaces
pm3d coloring
pm3d hidden surfaces
3D mapping
shaded error region
azimuth
circles and polygons
lighting model
```

[image]

### Coordinate and axis transforms

```
linked axes
nonlinear axes
broken axes
polar coords
polar functions
polar data
cylindrical/spherical
time/date coords
coord sampling ranges
```

[image]

### Binary and Image data

```
binary data
image data
binary and image tricks
RGB + alpha channel
bar chart art
```

[image]

### Colors

```
data-dependent coloring
RGB coloring
RGB + alpha channel
pm3d colors
pm3d gamma
```

[image]

### Sample Applications

```
control models
discrete contours
financial data
iteration
non-gridded data
running averages
automatic binning
binning/histograms
arrays
fence plots
Gantt chart
2D and 3D heat maps
solar path diagram
violin plot
```

[image]

### Text options

```
rotated text
'enhanced' text
string data
boxed text
variable font size
string variables
hypertext (no png support)
```

[image]

### Page Layout

```
multiplot layout
multiple plots
aligned plots
axis location
axis ticmarks
rectangles
customized key
```

[image]

### Styles

```
line and arrow styles
fill styles
dashed lines
transparency
transparent solids
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Extensive answer, but all this requires programming. It really isn't quite what Grapher.app is all about.